# overloading >> operator for stack list class

Tags: c++, stack, cin

```
LongInt i1; 

cin >> i1;
```

where LongInt is a class that contains a stack of integers. I want to store the input into the stack in the class and I assume that means I have to overload the >> operator in my class file. The problem is that I'm not sure how to push inputs like cin >> "111343241" into a stack digit by digit. How would I make this work?

Comment: Pls share your approach.

Comment: Wait, what does `cin >> "111343241"` mean? You can't take input and then put it into a string. Did you mean `output << i1;`?

Comment: I meant cin >> 193241924924, just some number that can't be stored in regular int. I have a LongInt class where I have a data field called s1, but I don't even know where to start to break up cin to give me digit by digit

Comment: There are LOTS of examples on how to overload `operator>>`. You have definitely not even tried googling this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To overload the operator itself, implementing the get loop, define a namespace-scope

```
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& is, LongInt& li) {
    char c;
    while( is.get(c).good() ) {
        if( !std::isdigit(c) ) {
             is.unget();
             break;
        }

        ...push it to li
    }

    return is;
}
```

How you push single digits to the LongInt depends on your implementation of LongInt.

Comment: Your loop-condition should just be `while(is.get(c))`.